# Меню при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку <kbd>Меню</kbd> появлялись все категории("Портфолио"), а подгруппы: свадьбы, беременность появлялись только после нажатия на кнопку <kbd>портфолио</kbd>.

[image: Изображение проекта]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".navigation").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("opened");
  });
});
```

Comment: @And Rey а нельзя в этом коде поменять?    
var main_menu = jQuery(".navigation");
var main_menu_container = main_menu.find('.nav').first();
var submenuHeight = main_menu_container.outerHeight();
main_menu.click(function() {
if(jQuery(window).outerWidth() <= 720) {
if(main_menu.hasClass("opened")) {
main_menu_container.animate({
'height': 0
}, 500, function() {
main_menu.removeClass("opened");
});
} else {
main_menu.addClass("opened");
var h = submenuHeight;
main_menu_container.css('height', '0');
main_menu_container.animate({
'height': h + "px"
}, 500);
}
}

Comment: Здравствуйте **Сева**! Поставил минус вашему вопросу. Для такого меню нужно вам предоставить HTML(и CSS желательно). Добавьте код, с радостью уберу минус.

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял, то нужно блок с подгруппами обернуть в какой нибудь див, задать этому диву display:none; и задать событие при клике на ссылку "Портфолио"

```
$(".portfolio").click(function(){

    $(".podmenu").slideToggle();
});
```

Как то так примерно

Тэг можно обернуть jquery

```
$(".item").wrap("<div class='new'></div>");
```

Comment: Спасибо,что откликнулись!
Проблема еще состоит в том,что работаю на движке Joomla и где там найти тот файл,в котором можно обернуть в див,понятия не имею=(
уже бьюсь с этой задачей 4 час(

Comment: Поправил ответ, как вариант можно так. Но лучше разобраться в Вашей cms и обернуть непосредственно в html